# Display big red warning on New User standard layout page

Tags: page-layout, standardlayout

In one of my customer's orgs, if some fields are populated when User is created (e.g. Address), certain business processes will kick off via Apex.

Ideally, we would prompt the user on save if those fields were blank that 'hey this process won't kick off'. As so many other things with SF, this is still in 'ideas' bucket from 13 years ago:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC

Now the next best thing I found was to add an image formula field or a visualforce page to the layout. Which would've worked were it not for the fact that neither of these render in the New/Edit experience for `User` object as that is basically Classic embedded into Lightning.

All target users are using LEX.

Any suggestions on what else can be done?

**Update** Since the 'new user' UX can't be overriden nor disabled, some 'other page' elsewhere in the org simply won't cut it, as users are familiar with 'how to create users' and if that can't be disabled, they will never go to that new page even if I managed to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

To populate such kind of popup based on some conditions seems to be not possible via standard tools available in Salesforce. As a workaround, You can override the button for lightning with a Lightning Component which has such capabilities.

For user new button in setup, We cannot override, but we can place the Lightning Web component somewhere in lightning, I mean an App Page or home page.

Comment: Can you override this button for `User` object specifically?

Comment: i have updated the answer. Please check

Comment: so that doesn't help me a single bit, my question is specific to users, and since i can't disable the UX when 'new user' is clicked, some 'other page elsewhere' does not help me at all.